# Django loop to without loop using orm

Tags: django, python-3.x, orm

In the following code i am converting date_no to day of the week.So i have to loop 7 times for each day.And query is executing 7 times.But i want to change this code such that there is no loop and query to run is only one.

```
        day_wise = {}
        for date_no in range(1,7):
            # Total 7 queryies 
             BusinessShareInfo_result = BusinessShareInfo.objects.filter(Date__week_day=date_no).all()
             day_wise[calendar.day_name[date_no]] = {'Average':0,'Maximum':0,'Minimum':0 }
             data = BusinessShareInfo_result.aggregate(Avg('Turnover'), Max('Turnover'), Min('Turnover') )
             day_wise[calendar.day_name[date_no]]['Average'] = data['Turnover__avg']
             day_wise[calendar.day_name[date_no]]['Maximum'] = data['Turnover__max']
             day_wise[calendar.day_name[date_no]]['Minimum'] = data['Turnover__min']
```

I just want the functionality to be same but without any loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you do not write any loop, you still make loops, for example to fetch the database. This looping is not that inefficient. What *is* inefficient is making seven queries, because making a query, regardless what the query is, is already expensive by itself.

You can make use of an [**`ExtractWeekDay`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractWeekDay) to reduce the number of queries to *one*:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay

qs = BusinessShareInfo.objects.values(
    week_day=ExtractWeekDay('Date')
).annotate(
    Average=Avg('Turnover')
    Max=Max('Turnover')
    Min=Min('Turnover')
)

result = {
    calendar.day_name[r['week_day']]: {
        'Average': r['Average'],
        'Max': r['Max'],
        'Min': r['Min'],
    }
    for r in qs
}
```

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `date` instead of <s>`Date`</s>.

Comment: SHOWING Cannot resolve keyword 'Day' into field. Choices are: Close, Date, High, Low, Opens, Shares_Traded, Turnover, id.

Comment: @PravinMishra: the field from which we want to extract is `'Date'`, made a typo.

Comment: @PravinMishra: well the weekdays start at `1` and end at `7`, so if the day names start at `0`, you should change it to `calendar.day_name[r['week_day']-1]` to compensate.